# File Server Resource Manager attempting to access quota.xml on System Reserved partition?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, file-server, quota

I've got a new install of Server 2008 R2 that is designed to be our quota server for user home directories and shared areas. I installed FSRM and set up a few quotas to try out. They worked fine but at some point over the weekend it's stopped loading the FSRM console quota screen and gives the following error, with Event ID 8228:

```
File Server Resource Manager was unable to access the following file or volume: '\\?\Volume{73649de6-7f04-11e1-a344-005056b10310}\System Volume Information\SRM\quota.xml'. This file or volume might be locked by another application right now, or you might need to give Local System access to it.
```

I have removed and reinstalled the FSRM Role Service, cleared the \System Volume Information\SRM folder on each volume and am at the verge of just starting again. I'd rather not since then I have to go through and set up all my NTFS permissions again.

Since it looks like the service is trying to access the System Reserved partition, which I assume won't have any files it could possibly need, **how do I remove System Reserved partition as a volume to be monitored for the quota service?** (I am not aware of configuring that to be the case originally though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that deleting the contents of the \System Volume Information\SRM directory and giving the server time to recover has resolved the issue.

A very unsatisfying answer!